# What are the proper ways to use "age and "aged"?

Tags: word-usage

So, I have recently written a school assignment in English and I was wondering what's the correct way to say:

1. In the beginning of the 19th century, one-third of the millworkers aged from seven to twelve.
2. In the beginning of the 19th century, one-third of the millworkers were between the age of seven and twelve.
3. In the beginning of the 19th century, one-third of the millworkers were between seven and twelve.

My teacher doesn't approve of the first example that I have listed.

Comment: Likely because in your first example, *aged* has to be the verb, so you're saying that one-third of the millworkers became older by five years.

Comment: 1) is not a sentence. That might be the problem. Did you ask your teacher why 1) was NG?

Comment: @deadrat I think a construct like "a millworker aged twelve" is still correct, if somewhat obsolete.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski I agree, and see 3169's take: if we read according to the construct you mention, we don't have a complete sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The second two sentences are good.  The first is close, but *aged* can have ambiguous use unless you give more information.  Any way I try to interpret the sentence as written, it doesn't work.

Let's say I interpret *aged* as the verb "to grow older".  Then the meaning of the first sentence is

> One-third of the millworkers got five years older, specifically from seven to twelve.

On the other hand, if I interpret it as the adjective phrase (as you mention in your comment) the sentence is incomplete because it lacks a verb.

> One-third of the millworkers, aged seven to twelve, ... (did something?)

The construct you seem to be trying to create is this:

> ... one-third of the millworkers were aged seven to twelve.

This would be fine, although it's more natural to say something like:

> ... one-third of the millworkers were from seven to twelve years old.